# NuGet restore Vs NuGet installer

Tags: tfs, nuget-package-restore

I am using TFS 2015. I want to restore nuget packages on build.
while defining my build definition, I find "NuGet restore" task with name NuGet restore.

But, I find that "NuGet Installer" task with name NuGet restore is used in solutions provided by other people while I was researching at the ways to restore nuget package.  I cannot find "NuGet Installer". is it available only in VSTS and not in TFS 2015?

can anyone please tell me the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the **NuGet Installer** task in TFS 2015 and **NuGet Restore** task in TFS 2017 and later version (including VSTS) have the same function to restore the packages for solutions. But the new **NuGet Restore** task in TFS 2017 and later version is more flexible and feature-rich, it also has different versions.

The name "**NuGet Installer**" is the display name of the `NuGet Restore` task, in TFS 2017 and later version inculding VSTS we can custom the **Display name**. And in TFS 2015 we can also edit the display name, but seems they shown in different ways.

**Conclusion** : Do not focus on the task or display name as we can custome it. Just focus on the functions. See [Package: NuGe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget)t task for details.

[image]