# How to configure older version of package with packages available on TFS server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008, nuget

I have a VS 2008 file that runs on my computer perfectly fine and does everything it needs to do. When I update the TFS version of it its copies exactly, just as you'd expect. However when I build my solution on TFS it can't find a package in my packages folder in my project folder.

This all makes sense, the `.gitignore` has it set so that packages in the project are removed (unless necessary), and my company uses nuget to deal with all common 3rd party packages used. That being said, how do I get a reference to the package (with appropriate version) from the TFS server to my code on TFS?

P.S. This is my first time dealing with this tech so apologies if the lingo is being misused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How to configure older version of package with packages available on TFS server

If you are using the TFS version is 2015 or above, there is NuGet Installer or NuGet Restore task, which you could use to restore the nuget package from the package source to the work directory when you build your project:

Check the document [Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/?view=azure-devops) and [NuGet restore Vs NuGet installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833086/nuget-restore-vs-nuget-installer).

If you are using the TFS version is 2013 and below, you can 
check the document [Integrate NuGet Package Restore TFS Build 2013 or Older to restore nuget packages](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/integrate-nuget-package-restore-tfs-build/).

Hope this helps.